# Can $\prod_{k=1}^n (a_k z^2 + b_k z + c_k) - c_1c_2\dots c_n$ have roots in the right half-plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

Let $a_k$, $b_k$, $c_k$ for $k \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ be *nonnegative* real numbers such that $a_k+b_k > 0$ for all $k$. Let
$$
p(z) = \prod_{k=1}^n (a_k z^2 + b_k z + c_k) - c_1c_2\dots c_n, \qquad z \in \mathbb{C}.
$$
Clearly $p(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$, that is $p$ has no roots on the positive half-line. Is it true for the right half-plane?

> Is it true that $p(z) \neq 0$ for all $z$ such that $\mathrm{Re}(z) > 0$?

Is it possible to somehow bound $|p(z)|$ from below on the right half-plane? Or maybe I should use Rouche's theorem?